# How to start several aws instances with different IP addresses with one query?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I do:

```
ec2-run-instances ami_id -n 10 ...
```

then 10 instances will be started.
They will have random IP addresses from the specified subnet.

How do I start 10 instances with the IP addresses that I need (say 1,2,3..10)?

The obvious solution, to make a loop and start instances in it,
is incorrect, because *it does not allow to start instances with one query*.

Why is it important? There are some tasks like for example *network placement group* you need to start instances in one turn.

Comment: Why -1 and close requests? This question is not simple or obvious as it shines.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only specify "primary private IP" for individual instance if you use DHCP.  (this apply to spot instance as well).
2. AWS will RESERVED 5(4 IP starting from subnet, and the last IP of the subnet) IP address for EVERY subnet CIDR. So for CIDR/24, you cannot use IP address that end with 1,2,3,4 and 255.   So you cannot create subnet beyond CIDR/29.
3. If you insist to specify your own IP, you must create your own script to launch instance that load primary private IP parameter incrementally, and must not use 1,2,3,4 and 255.

Comment: The only solution that could solve the problem is 3, but it obviously will not work, because you need to do it in *one turn*

Comment: @IgorChubin : Assign IP addresses into array/list/set variable, then loop them.

Comment: No! That will not work, because it is not one query in this case!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--private-ip-address` option to the  [run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) command:

Comment: The main point of the question: how to do it in **one turn** for several instances